# Handsontable - excessive cell rendering slowing down application

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

I've created a Handsontable that displays data coming from a database, via Rails. Currently, there are 99 rows in the table. The far left "selected" column displays a pseudo-checkbox (using a custom cell renderer) indicating whether the user has selected the row. The data schema also includes a "selected" property. When the user selects one or more columns, the "selected" properties for the corresponding rows are toggled in the data object, and this causes the changed cells to re-rendered to reflect the change.

The problem is that, for any change made to *any* editable column, every "selected" cell that is visible is re-rendered.  To demonstrate, in the attached jsFiddle, both the far-left "selected" column and the far-right "Prom" columns are editable. A counter above the table shows the number of times that the "selected" cell renderer has been called (for simplicity, a X is shown in the "selected" column, rather than a checkbox).  You can see that simply clicking the row 1 "selected" cell causes selectColRenderer to be called 21 times. Clicking that same cell and dragging down to row 5 (remaining in the "selected" column) causes the cell renderer to be called 105 times. Entering text in any of the the "Prom" column cells also generates 21 calls to the cell renderer.

In my application, I have a "Select All" button that selects all 99 objects in the data model.  If 28 of those rows are visible, selectColRenderer is called 99*28 time --> almost 2800 calls to the cell renderer. It takes three to four seconds for the changes to be reflected in the browser.

This is the (simplified) cell renderer function:

```
var selectColRenderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  // the following 2 lines are only part of the fiddle
  renderCount++;
  $("#render_count").val(renderCount);
  if (instance.getSourceDataAtRow(cellProperties.row).selected == true) {
     $(td).html("X");
  } else {
    $(td).html("");
  }
};
```

And this is the function that updates the data model:

```
afterSelectionEnd: function(r1, c1, r2, c2) {
  hot = $("#list_table").handsontable("getInstance");
  if (c1 === 0 && c2 === 0) {
     for (r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
       objRow = hot.getCellMeta(r, 0).row;
       var selected = (hot.getSourceDataAtRow(objRow).selected)
       hot.setDataAtRowProp(r, "selected", !selected);
     }
  }
},
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?  If I have a table with hundreds of rows, the performance will be unacceptable.  Is this how Handsontable works, or am I doing something wrong?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jplato/u9japmqg/

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation, I fixed this. It appears that the optimal way to update multiple columns is using setDataAtCell() and passing a 2D array of the changes to be made to each cell, rather than using setDataAtRowProp() and passing the changes individually.